# Jest capture input change event and verify it was called with the correct value on a controlled react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, dom-events, react-testing-library

I am trying to use `jest` and `@testing-library/react` to verify that a react component (*which wraps an HTML `input` element*) is calling it's `onChange` callback with the correct value in response to a ChangeEvent.

Here is the react component

```
export const MyInput = ({ onChange, value }) => {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    onChange(event);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        label={"test-component"}
        data-testid={"test"}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is the test

```
test("onChange should work", () => {
  const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
  let inputValue = 1;

  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <MyInput onChange={onChangeMock} value={inputValue} />
  );
  const input = getByTestId("test");

  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "23" } });

  expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({
      target: expect.objectContaining({
        value: "23"
      })
    })
  );
});
```

And here is a [link to a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-forked-tm7qjz) which reproduces the problem.

The second assertion in my tests fails, because the `onChangeMock`'s caller is an event whose' `target.value` is equal to `1`, rather than `23`.

And what's even weirder is that when logging `event.target.value` inside the `handleChange` function - it has the correct value of `23`. Inspecting with a debugger also shows that the jest mock has a correct caller (event with a target value of `23` up until the debugger leaves the scope of the `handleChange` function). The moment I get back to the test scope and perform the assertion, the mock's event has a target value of 1.

So I am trying to understand **Why am I observing this behavior and what is causing it ?**

*(I assume that the event's target gets set (by what though?) to my html input element the moment the event handler scope ends, and jest does not capture a deep clone of the event, as it was passed to the external function, but I could not find any documentation to support this)*

Comment: the crazy thing is even if i change `onChangeMock` into
```js
const onChangeMock = e =>{
 console.log("mock", e.target.value)
}
```

it will console `mock 23`;

Comment: [this link](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable) might be of use. What i learn is if an `input` is controlled and the `value` props is not changed, `e.target.value` will be forced back into its set `value` after the call. sure they will refer to the same `event`. but that same `event` has different `target.value` now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React uses [synthetic events](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#react-event-object) instead of native DOM events, they behave similarly but not exactly the same, synthetic events are nullified after the handler handler is executed, for illustration, try this with the event handler from your code:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
  onChange(event); // 23
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }, 3000); // 1
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text input is not effecting changes because your code is not treating it like a [Controlled Input](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

In short, the test is expecting the right things, but the component is ignoring changes.

Try this:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export const MyInput = ({ onChange, value }) => {
  const [controlledValue, setControlledValue] = useState(value);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setControlledValue(event.target.value);
    onChange(event);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        label={"test-component"}
        data-testid={"test"}
        value={controlledValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You'll see a similar example in [Testing Library InputEvent docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-input-event/)

Comment: Yes, making the input's value be controlled by the input resolves this - but this is not what I am after.

I am trying to understand why my example fails. Since the event that gets dispatched by `fireEvent.change()` is actually accepted by the component, and it does call the onChange callback with the correct value. (as mentioned in my reply, if I inspect the callers of the jest mock, while I'm in the scope oh handleChange), the event is correct. 

But the moment JS exits the scope of handleChange, the event stored in the callers of the jest mock starts pointing to the unmodified input

Comment: Good point. When I log `event.target`, it is a FiberNode which admittedly I haven't delved deep into. Could it be that? I also see value is a Getter/Setter (although logging `event.target.value` is "23" of type string.
 `value: [Getter/Setter]`

Comment: Not sure, if its the FiberNode, hence my question here :D